# How can I seal the openings for the armrest of this chair nicely?

Tags: hole, hole-repair

I have recently acquired a Steelcase Leap chair (https://www.steelcase.com/products/office-chairs/leap/)
but I do not have the arm rests. I don't want them in the first place because they would get in the way in my small home office.

However I did not expect to see two holes, one on each side. Apparently there is no cover comes with this unit.

The opening on the left hand side

[image: The opening on the left hand side]

The opening on the left hand side with the soft plastic outer cover of the shaft been removed

[image: The opening on the left hand side with the soft plastic outer cover of the shaft been removed]

I have checked Steelcase website but they don't have this kind of parts.

Is there any good component/material I can purchase from a hardware store so I can use to seal the openings?

Comment: Sure you can't just remove the armrest base? That looks like the adjustable part was scavenged/removed before you acquired the rest of the chair,  without also removing the base. Typically (don't know your particular chair, but In general) the armrest base is itself removable from the rest of the chair (or never installed in the first place on a new chair being assembled where you don't want arms)

Comment: Armless is an option per the website. That is almost always not a "whole different chair" just parts not installed/supplied. They don't have "covers for the holes" in all likelihood because you just remove the parts with holes if you don't want arms. Flip the chair over and look for hardware to unscrew.

Answer (score 1):

You could use scissors to cut an oval plastic shape just bigger than the hole, use an old milk carton or soda bottle. Paint it black and set it on the white socket, than slide the plastic cover down over to hold it.

Or... remove the arm assemblies entirely.

Comment: It is a great suggestion. What kind of paint will do for the job?

Comment: I would use any black spray paint I had on hand, and touch up as needed. Best would be specialty spray for plastics.